# Determining if $f:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\implies\mathbb{R}, f(x)=x-y $ is onto or surjective

Tags: functions

Not sure how to determine this.

$w\in\mathbb{R}, w=x-y\implies x=w+y$ and $y=x-w$.

So that $f(x,y)=(y+w)-(x-w)=2w+y-x$.

The thing is I think this is in Rng(f) but not sure how  apparent that is or how to further prove it or reduce it to just w.

Intuitively, I would say that $\mathbb{R}\subseteq Rng(f)$ because you can get any $r\in\mathbb{R}$ from x-y, both in $\mathbb{R}$ and 2w+y-x will also be in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

For any $w \in \Bbb R$, does there exist $x$ such that $f(x)=w$, i.e., $x-y=w$?

Comment: Yes? If I only consider X, I can fix y=0 and this is true for all x in R and all w in R, but do I use this approach? Am I just confusing the issue trying to have x and y both be independent variables?

Comment: Of course you can fix one of the variables to reach some particular value, as in this case: $\;\forall\,w\in\Bbb R\;,\;\;f(w,0)=w\implies f\;$ is surjective.